# How to make Qlabel with a triagular tip

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I am trying to make a Qlabel looks like modern chat bubbles in messengers (round rect with a triangular tip) like in this image:

[image]

I have managed to make the qlabel have one sharp edge but can't get how to make the tip. the problem was to insert a triangular path at the corner, the qlabel round rect and the text should be shifted in the opposite direction, but making this leads the text go out of the label area

Here is a sub-classed label with overridden paint events and resize events ( resize used in word wrapping which is outside my problem scope-maybe)> I removed some unnecessary code related to coloring, fonts,..etc

```py
class chatLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self,text):
        super(chatLabel, self).__init__(text)
        self.setContentsMargins(6,6,6,6)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed,QSizePolicy.Expanding )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.color = QtGui.QColor("#333C43")

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, False)
        rect =  QtCore.QRectF(0,0,self.width()-1,self.height()-1)
        p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill )
        path.addRoundedRect(rect, 15.0, 15.0)
        path.addRect(self.width()-13, 0, 13, 13)
        p.fillPath(path, self.color)

       super(chatLabel, self).paintEvent(e)

    def resizeEvent(self, e): #Due to a bug in Qt, we need this. ref:https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37673
        #heightForWidth rely on minimumSize to evaulate, so reset it before
        self.setMinimumHeight( 0 )

        # define minimum height
        self.setMinimumHeight( self.heightForWidth( self.width() ) )
        if self.width()>256:
            self.setWordWrap(True)
            self.setMinimumWidth(128)

        super(chatLabel, self).resizeEvent(e)
```

This the result of the above sub-classed label

[image]

How can I reach the look I want?
N.B: I am aware I can do it with images, but this requires scaling image (9-slice) according to text size

Comment: I tested it ^^  but the tip is very small, this will work if on left as the problem of shifted text won't appear, as the tip is put in the empty area near the corner 

but this is not what the above image does ^^

Comment: the problem till now is that somehow we need to shift the text without going out of the label
we shift the round rect (to leave a margin for the tip) and need to shift the text also but keeping it also inside the round rect

Comment: And It seems to be exact I add the triangle to the leftbottom...

Comment: top or left is not a problem, 
the important is left, right tip has no problem.

Comment: I updated again. And I will delete unnecessary comment!

Comment: @user9402680 Thank's, but if you tried to make the tip on the left,, you will see that the problem still exitsts

Comment: Ouch! In the case of white, I couldn't pay attention to the stinger.ok, thanks to reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a simple solution for my problem.

Since the problem was that if I made a tip at the right corner, a shift in the text is required to make the text contained inside the round rect (the bubble). We can make this shift by using padding in style sheets which will make the text shifted from the corner. So, the text will appear as it is included in the bubble.

Thank's to user9402680's answer and his code snippet, I added style sheet line to it to achieve the required effect.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
class chatLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,text):
        super(chatLabel, self).__init__(text)
        self.setContentsMargins(6,6,6,6)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed,QSizePolicy.Expanding )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.color = QColor("#333C43")
        # 17 px margin from right (to make the text included in the bubble
        # 8  px margin from left. 
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel{padding: 0px 8px 0px 17px;}")


    def paintEvent(self, e):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, False)
        #I changed this width from - 1 to - 16 because I can't see the result good.
        rect =  QRectF(0,0,self.width()- 16,self.height()-1)
        p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill )
        path.addRoundedRect(rect, 15.0, 15.0)
        #I deleted this object
#        path.addRect(self.width()-13, 0, 13, 13)

        linePath = QPainterPath()
        linePath.moveTo(rect.right() + rect.width()/6 , rect.top())
        linePath.lineTo(rect.right() - rect.width()/2, rect.bottom())
        linePath.lineTo(rect.right() , rect.top() - rect.height()/3)
#        linePath.lineTo(rect.right() - rect.width()/5, rect.top() - rect.height()/2)
        path = path.united(linePath)
        #cubic bezier curve, please try this , too.
#        cubicPath =QPainterPath()
#        cubicPath.moveTo(rect.right() - 20, rect.top())
#        cubicPath.cubicTo(rect.right() - 20, rect.top() + rect.height()/2, rect.right() , rect.top() , rect.right() + 15, rect.top())
#        path = path.united(cubicPath)

        p.fillPath(path, self.color)

        super(chatLabel, self).paintEvent(e)

    def resizeEvent(self, e): #Due to a bug in Qt, we need this. ref:https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37673
        #heightForWidth rely on minimumSize to evaulate, so reset it before
        self.setMinimumHeight( 0 )

        # define minimum height
        self.setMinimumHeight( self.heightForWidth( self.width() ) )
        if self.width()>256:
            self.setWordWrap(True)
            self.setMinimumWidth(128)

        super(chatLabel, self).resizeEvent(e)
def main():
    try:
        app=QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    widget = chatLabel("This is the result!")
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
class chatLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,text):
        super(chatLabel, self).__init__(text)
        self.setContentsMargins(6,6,6,6)
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed,QSizePolicy.Expanding )
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        self.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.color = QColor("#333C43")

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, False)
        #I changed this width from - 1 to - 16 because I can't see the result good.
        rect = QRectF(16,0,self.width()- 16,self.height()-1)
        p.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.setFillRule(Qt.WindingFill )
        path.addRoundedRect(rect, 15.0, 15.0)
        #I deleted this object
#        path.addRect(self.width()-13, 0, 13, 13)

        linePath = QPainterPath() linePath.moveTo(rect.left() - rect.width()/6 ,rect.top()) 
        linePath.lineTo(rect.left() + rect.width()/2, rect.bottom()) 
        linePath.lineTo(rect.left() , rect.top() - rect.height()/3)
#       linePath.lineTo(rect.right() - rect.width()/5, rect.top() - rect.height()/2)
        path = path.united(linePath)
        #cubic bezier curve, please try this , too.
#        cubicPath =QPainterPath()
#        cubicPath.moveTo(rect.right() - 20, rect.top())
#        cubicPath.cubicTo(rect.right() - 20, rect.top() + rect.height()/2, rect.right() , rect.top() , rect.right() + 15, rect.top())
#        path = path.united(cubicPath)

        p.fillPath(path, self.color)

        super(chatLabel, self).paintEvent(e)

    def resizeEvent(self, e): #Due to a bug in Qt, we need this. ref:https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37673
        #heightForWidth rely on minimumSize to evaulate, so reset it before
        self.setMinimumHeight( 0 )

        # define minimum height
        self.setMinimumHeight( self.heightForWidth( self.width() ) )
        if self.width()>256:
            self.setWordWrap(True)
            self.setMinimumWidth(128)

        super(chatLabel, self).resizeEvent(e)
def main():
    try:
        app=QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    widget = chatLabel("This is the result!")
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```